# Why Rich-Results doesn't catch generate structured data with javascript

Tags: reactjs, next.js, seo, google-search-console, json-ld

Generate structured data with javascript. But structured data testing tool doesn't catch any data.
Why Rich-Results doesn't catch generate structured data with javascript.

Google Doc Said:

> Google can read JSON-LD data when it is **dynamically** injected into the page's contents, such as by JavaScript code or embedded widgets in your content management system.

from this [doc](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/intro-structured-data)
and [how to do reference](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/generate-structured-data-with-javascript#custom-javascript) here.

But [Testing tool](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results) doesn't catch the data.

Test Page:
[Page A](https://app.wondercise.com/studio/course/24?timeslotId=2182), [Page B](https://app.wondercise.com/studio/course)

Page's JSON-LD data is correct, I copy to [Testing tool](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results), it can found.

Web page is build by Next.js^10.2.3.
I used server-side render structured-data before.
Encountered page large than 1M, can't load page.
So I changed it to client-side dynamically injected into the page's contents.

```
import React from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { map, keys } from 'ramda';

function SeoSchema({ schema }: { schema: Object }) {
  // client side render only
  if (!process.browser) return null;

  return (
    <Head>
      {/* schema */}
      {map((key) => (
        schema[key] && (
          <script
            type="application/ld+json"
            key={`schema-${key}`}
            // eslint-disable-next-line
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: JSON.stringify(schema[key]) }}
          />
        )
      ), keys(schema))}
    </Head>
  );
}

export default SeoSchema;
```

What I'm missing?
If there no answer, I will change back to server-side render structured-data.